# Return names when vectors match vectors

Tags: r

So I am trying to loop through a matrix and finding the names that match a given template (either full match or NA)

```
for (i in 3:3000){
if(all(template == dataset[i,colnames(dataset)%in%template],na.rm=TRUE)) print(dat[i,1])
}
##The 2nd line returns TRUE if all variables match or are NA
```

The 'template' variable would be a variable length. In the example below, it is 12 columns wide. The variable 'thing_to_match' is again a subset of of variables from dataset.

```
"ID" "V1" "V5" "V7" "V10" "V1000"
Bob  A B NA J U
```

This vector (thing_to_match) is merely a subset of special variables from the "dataset". I want this for loop to go through the full dataset and return all the variables match or are NA for the special subset of variables.

```
>dataset
ID V1 V2 V3...V1000
Joe H A Z...G
Jim J T W ...N
Kathy A B U...U
```

Assume Kathy matches perfectly with Bob because all her variable match Bob's or are NA. My question is the above code does not work. I know there are ~50 matching variables in my dataset, but it is only returning 1 (in this case, it returns "Bob" who is in the dataset also).

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please add the results of dput(template) and dput(head(dataset)) to your question. Also, what is the relationship between dataset and dat?